# Getting error for if condition in xslt on string comparison

Tags: oracle, xslt, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to compare value of node to string, but it is throwing error as below :

> ORA-06550:line 264, column 40: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Y"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>
> *_= - + ;  at in is mod remainder not rem
>    <> or!= or ~=>=<=<> and or like like2
>   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
>   The symbol "* was inserted before "Y" to continue.

Below is my code:

```
<xsl:if test="/email/threshold/text() = 'Y'">
```

If I remove single quote from "Y", it won't satisfy condition. What am I missing?
Using code below also doen't work.

```
<xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(email/threshold)=N)">
```

Comment: Are you sure it is that XSLT that is causing a problem? I see you've tagged this "oracle" and "ORA-06550" is an Oracle error, so perhaps the cause is elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: yes @TimC. Without it code works perfectly

Comment: That is a tiny fragment of your code. I'd imagine that fragment is actually part of a string, so you need to escape the single quotes around the Y, but it's hard to tell just from that.

Comment: Yes, After escaping it, it worked. It is strange because earlier in another database server same code was working fine.After changing database this error surfaced. Oracle version was changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely explanation is that the fragment you've shown is part of a string literal, in which case you either need to escape the single quotes around the `Y` (so the first single quote isn't interpreted as the end of that string, leaving the `Y` orphaned outside the string):

```
<xsl:if test="/email/threshold/text() = ''Y''">
```

or use [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) so escaping isn't necessary.

You can see the same thing with a simple anonymous block:

```
declare
  x varchar2(200);
begin
 x:='...
<xsl:if test="/email/threshold/text() = 'Y'">
...';
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 42:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Y" when expecting one of the following:
...
```

But either of these compile OK:

```
declare
  x varchar2(200);
begin
 x:='...
<xsl:if test="/email/threshold/text() = ''Y''">
...';
end;
/

declare
  x varchar2(200);
begin
 x:=q'|...
<xsl:if test="/email/threshold/text() = ''Y''">
...|';
end;
/
```

.. with the latter using the bar symbol `|` as the *quote_delimiter*.